# Problems with OpAmp based amplifier simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, simulation, multisim

I'm trying to simulate a simple amplifier for an electret microphone, but having problems regarding the output level and virtual ground.

The circuit in Multisim is as follows:
[image: Circuit Diagram]

What I'm having trouble understanding is:

- **Why is the virtual ground at 3v and not 2.5v?**
- **Why is the output swing 3x larger than the input swing and not ~100x?**

Also, here's a scope trace which may be useful: (input - orange (ch.A), output - red (ch.B))
[image: Scope Trace]

**Edit:**
Here are the currents in the feedback network:

[image: Current in feedback resistors]

Comment: Where is the DC current through R1 flowing?  Also the current in R5 & R6?

Comment: Also what's the reactance of 1uF at 1kHz?

Comment: I would suggest replacing your virtual ground with a real voltage source in your simulation, then when you get everything working decide what you want to do about a virtual ground.

Comment: Replacing VGND with a voltage source solves the alignment problem, I'll have a look at the currents in a second.

Comment: DC current through R1 flows through the AC source to ground. I've added a picture showing the currents in R5 & R6.

Comment: But those currents aren't actually flowing to ground, they are flowing through R3 to ground in the case of your virtual ground being there.  That lifts the potential above the 2.5V you are expecting.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. What about the gain problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16447/discussion-between-tehwalris-and-john-d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DC currents through R1 and R5 are flowing through R3, causing the virtual ground to increase in voltage.  According to the OP the gain is working correctly now.